# How do I set the buffer size using Oracle spool?

Tags: oracle, spool

I'm running a sql script using `spool` but the output is so long that not all of it is getting exported and saved into the output file. The output ends up looking like:

```
'first_item'|'first_col DOUBLE, second_field DOUBLE, third_field VARCHAR
'second_item'|'the_first DOUBLE, the_second DOUBLE, the_third DOUBLE, th
'third_item'|'field_1 VARCHAR(200), field_2 VARCHAR(100), field_3 VARCHA
```

That's what the file shows. Each line has a total of 80 characters in my file. If I run the query from within SQL Developer though, I can expand the column and see all of it. I'm running this script from the sqlplus command prompt.

I've played around with the following settings but can't get this to output the entire line:

```
SET LINESIZE ###
SET FLUSH OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
```

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do. I just want to get the entire field and display/output it

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I noticed that there were 80 characters in each line, since I'm basically doing string building with all my columns. I know one is supposed to be big, which caused the length of some records to be really big.

So I did a quick `ctrl+f` on the docs page and came across `SET LONG 1000`. The default is 80, so I changed that, which solved the issue.